# Discord Role Reaction Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Good evening, I have one major issue, my bot keeps reposting itself. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = 'channel ID';
        const TankRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Tank Role");
        const DpsRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Dps Role");
        const HealRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Heal Role");
 
        const TankEmoji = '️';
        const DpsEmoji = '';
        const HealEmoji = '';
 
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#fbfbfb')
            .setTitle('Welcome to !')
            .setThumbnail('https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.enjin.com/users/20685959/pics/full/4179214.jpg')
            .setDescription('Please select your roles below!\n\n'
                + `${TankEmoji} Tank\n`
                + `${DpsEmoji} Dps\n`
                + `${HealEmoji} Heal`)
                .setTimestamp()
 
        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(TankEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(DpsEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(HealEmoji);
 
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === TankEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(TankRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === DpsEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(DpsRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === HealEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(HealRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
 
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === TankEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(TankRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === DpsEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(DpsRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === HealEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(HealRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reposting itself?" Is it repeatedly sending the same message over and over?